# Solve Polynomial equation of 6th order with Python efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, polynomial-math

I want to Solve Polynomial equation of 6th order with Python.
I've tried the "basic" version:

```
avgIrms = 19.61
c_val = (0.000002324*avgIrms**6) - (0.0001527*avgIrms**5) + (0.003961843*avgIrms**4) - (0.052211292*avgIrms**3) + (0.379269091*avgIrms**2) -(0.404399274*avgIrms) + 0.000682896
print(c_val)
```

After that I've used the numpy with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
avgIrms = 19.61
ppar = [0.000002324, -0.0001527, 0.003961843, -0.052211292, 0.379269091, -0.404399274, 0.000682896]
p = np.poly1d(ppar)
print(p(avgIrms))
```

In the both ways the raspberry tooks more than five seconds to process... It's to much! Any help to solve polynomial equations efficiently? (less than one second...)

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: Do you mean "solving" the polynomial or evaluating it at a particular argument?  "Solving" a polynomial generally means finding the roots.  I can't imagine that you'll outperform numpy, using python, but look up "Horner's Method" in Wikipedia, if as it seems, you want to evaluate the polynomial.

Comment: When you say « [...] tooks more than five seconds [...] », how did you checked it?

Comment: I solved my problem with this:
def horner(coeffs, x):
 return reduce(lambda acc, c: acc * x + c, reversed(coeffs), 0)
 
def poli(value): 
 x = horner( (0.000682896, -0.404399274, 0.379269091, -0.052211292, 0.003961843, -0.0001527, 0.000002324), value)  
 return x

Comment: Would you post this as an answer then? I still don't see how this makes a speed-up compared to your "basic" evaluator. On my machine `horner` runs slower.

Comment: a sixth order polynomial could lead to overfitting.  the polynomial would have six root values.  you can use PolynomialFeatures(degree=6)

Answer (score 3):

First, what you want is to *evaluate* a polynomial for a given `x`, not to *solve* it. Second, I still don't see how do you get your speed up..

Find here a couple of timmings:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = 19.61
>>> pr = [0.000002324, -0.0001527, 0.003961843, -0.052211292, 0.379269091, -0.404399274, 0.000682896]
>>> p = pr[::-1] # reverse the order
```

- Hardcoded solution:

  ```
  >>> %timeit p[0] + x * p[1] + p[2] * x**2 + p[3] * x**3 + p[4] * x**4 + p[5] * x**5 + p[6] * x**6
  809 ns
  ```
- Loopy solution:

  ```
  >>> %%timeit
      val = 0
      for i in range(len(p)):
          val += p[i] * x**i
  1.24 µs
  ```
- Functional programming solution:

  ```
  >>> %timeit reduce(lambda acc, i: acc + p[i] * x**i, range(len(p)))
  1.61 µs
  ```
- Using numpy's `polyval`:

  ```
  >>> %timeit np.polyval(pr, x)
  6.12 µs
  ```
- Using numpy's `poly1d`

  ```
  >>> %%timeit
      c = np.poly1d(pr)
      c(x)
  9.46 µs
  ```

So, clearly numpy is slower, as for a such a small array it adds some overhead in the Python <-> C communication, but still, it is of the order of `6-9 µs`, I'm using a desktop computer, but I would be pretty impressed if a Raspberry Pi would really take 5 seconds to do that operation. Are you sure you did the timings properly?

Any way, either the hardcoded or the loopy solution seem faster than the functional programming one (the equivalent to the one that you defined as `horner` in your comment).